# How to change the port from 8020 to 80 in Aptana 3.0

Tags: localhost, port, aptana, aptana3

When I run my file from aptana on firefox (I click the little green play button on Aptana) I get this link on my firefox:

http://127.0.0.1:8020/MyAccount/index.php

but that doesn't displays anything. If I change the port to 80 or just delete it like this:

http://127.0.0.1/MyAccount/index.php

then all works - the question is - **how do I "tell" Aptana to go to the new link I have (so I can see the file) and what is generally the problem.**

I use wamp server if that can help solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to menu Run>Run configurations.

Once in there, go to the Web Browser section, choose your prefered web browser. On the right inside in the server section, tick the "Use selected Server" option and configure your server by following the instruction. When you enter the URL don't forget to add to the ip address followed by your project folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I could find the URL field, and when I start debugging, it tells me: `Launch URL is not defined`

Answer (score 4):

I use XAMMP as my server so I'm not sure if this will work with WAMMP.

Go to run configurations select Web Browser then choose which browser you want to use. Then in the main tab find use base URL and click on it. Enter `http://localhost/` and make sure that you check the append project name.

Make sure that your index page's name is index.html or index.php if hou are using php and try running it.

Comment: To specify a specific port, instead of `http://localhost/`, enter `http://localhost:portNum/`, like for port 8080, enter `http://localhost:8080/`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Project Properties > Preview Settings you can point to the specific server.

HTH

-Rb

Answer (score 0):

Change Port: Aptana Studio 3, Needed restart after changing the setting.

Preferences>Aptana Studio>Web Servers>Built In